# Configure Topics in Kafka broker itself or via Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have to define topics in my application.  I am using Spring Cloud Stream to configure messaging between application. Spring cloud stream uses kafka binder in the background.  I wonder what is the best way to create topics with partitions and replication factor.I wonder if we should configure it itself, or we should make it using application.properties.? What about if partition number can be a dynamic value  that depends on consumer number. Please give me hints to implement in correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka binder provides a topic provisioner as part of its implementation (`KafkaTopicProvisioner`). Therefore, if your broker allows automatic topic creation, the desired topic with the correct configurations can be created using the provisioner before any bindings take effect. If the topic does not already exist, the provisioner creates the topic for you. If you have a producer application, see this [blog](https://spring.io/blog/2021/02/03/demystifying-spring-cloud-stream-producers-with-apache-kafka-partitions) for a detailed explanation on the various configuration available for setting up partitions.

If you have a consumer application, then if the topic does not exist when the app starts, it creates the topic with `instanceCount * concurrency`. See [this implementation detail](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/main/binders/kafka-binder/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/provisioning/KafkaTopicProvisioner.java#L245) for that. If the topic exists, then it can still increase the number of partitions on the broker based on the `instanceCount` and `concurrency` settings, but it cannot decrease the number of partitions.

You can set the replication factor using the property - `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<input-binding>.consumer.topic.replicationFactor` for consumer apps and `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<ouptut-binding>.producer.topic.replicationFactor` for producer apps.

You can also provide [replicaAssignments](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/main/binders/kafka-binder/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/properties/KafkaTopicProperties.java#L34) using the same property prefixes.

In addition, you can pass along any arbitrary [topic configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs) using
`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<input-binding>.consumer.topic.properties` or `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<output-binding>.producer.topic.properties`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define `@Bean NewTopic` resources in your application configuration, either parsed from properties, or in code.

The partition count cannot be dynamic. You should know how many consumers are necessary ahead of time for absolute ordering or for max parallelism. Partition count can only ever increase, but doing so will lose ordering within the topic